# Hash table manual collision handling in Java

Tags: java, hashtable, collision

My task is to do a bank management system. The client accounts are kept inside the bank by using a hash table, so for each client, represented by a personal identification number, there will be an arraylist of accounts (a client can have at most 2 accounts - a saving account and a spending account).

What I have to do is to manually handle the collisions that could occur. How can I do that? What method do I have to override ? I have to mention that HashTables are not my cup of tea, as I had difficulty in working with them in C.

P.S. - I am planning to use HashMap as I understood is easier to work with.

**EDIT** - Manual collision handling is THE REQUIREMENT.

**EDIT 2** - It comes as a requirement because the lab assistant wants us to understand how hash tables work. After more digging, I guess that I need to override the "equals" method from Hashtable, so no HashMap. Is that a correct approach? (no new ADT needed)

Comment: Please explain how / why it is a requirement.  Are you required to implement your own hash tables in Java?

Comment: If the point is for *you* to handle collisions, then you need to build your own data structure (you can't use a `HashMap` as it *just works*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard hash table implementations do collision handling automatically and you have no control over that. What you must do however, is to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` for the objects used as key - but in the case of `String` / `Number`, that's also done by the standard library already.
So if the task is really for you to handle collisions - then you must build your own `Map` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

> What I have to do is to manually handle the collisions that could occur. How can I do that?

If it is a hard requirement that you do your own collision handling, you will need to implement the hash table from scratch.  You can't use `HashMap` or `HashTable` or any other existing class that I'm aware of ... because they all deal the collisions, etc, for you.

> I have to mention that HashTables are not my cup of tea, as I had difficulty in working with them in C.

How unfortunate.  You are going to have to understand them to complete this exercise.  (On second thoughts, perhaps this requirement is a GOOD THING ... if it forces you to understand properly how hash tables work.)

For the record, there are numerous good texts on data structures that explain how hash tables work.  And if you don't have a text book, [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) is pretty comprehensive.  Both a textbook and Wikipedia will describe various techniques for handling collisions.

---

> After more digging, I guess that I need to override the "equals" method from Hashtable, so no HashMap. Is that a correct approach? (no new ADT needed)

I don't think so.

- The `equals` method of `Hashtable` / `HashMap` has nothing to do with collision handling for hash table entries.
- The collision detection logic in a `Hashtable` / `HashMap` is in private methods, so you *cannot* override it directly.

I think that the lab assistant wants / expects you to implement a hash table ADT, and I don't see how you can avoid doing this.  But, hey, you could always *ask the lab assistant* what he or she *expects* you to do.

---

Bonus advice: the target type of the map should be a custom class that holds references to the two accounts, and also personal details for the user.  It shouldn't be an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Manual collision handling is a requirement. How can I do that with HashMap ?

Comment: @MihaiAndreiRustiuc the collision handling of HashMap is automatic, it does not expose methods for manual collision handling.

Comment: The teaching assistant posted it as a requirement so that we can understand HashTables and collisions better.

Comment: @josefx ok, then what should I use so that I can handle collisions manually?